# Ubuntu: почему функция "извлечь" на USB флешке оставляет битые файлы

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Записываю два фильма на USB флешку через Nautilus, размер каждого ~2 Гб.

Сначала показывается прогресс бар, первые сотни мегабайт записываются практически моментально, потом скорость резко падает. В конце окошко прогрессбара закрывается. Если после этого щелкнуть по значку флешки и выбрать "извлечь", показывается попап "диск был успешно извлечен".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но обычно второй файл становится битым где-то на середине. Вопрос: почему? Я ожидаю, что ОС скинет буфер ввода-вывода и только после этого разрешит извлечение. Если делать `sudo sync`, проблемы нет. Если не делать - стабильно повторяется.

PS. Ubuntu 16.04

`dmesg`

```
[  656.566475] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  656.567021] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 15730688 512-byte logical blocks: (8.05 GB/7.50 GiB)
[  656.567986] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  656.567989] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  656.568893] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  656.568899] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  656.573524]  sdc: sdc1
[  656.576879] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  666.791088] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  669.984170] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  670.095071] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[  670.095074] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  670.095076] usb 2-1.2: Product: Silicon-Power
[  670.095078] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: UFD 2.0
[  670.095079] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 1402036101500139
[  670.095498] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  670.095862] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[  671.506618] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UFD 2.0  Silicon-Power8G  1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  671.507034] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  671.507690] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 15730688 512-byte logical blocks: (8.05 GB/7.50 GiB)
[  671.508541] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  671.508545] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  671.509438] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  671.509446] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  671.515803]  sdc: sdc1
[  671.519015] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  699.075190] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  699.075192] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  699.075194] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  699.075196] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 58 00 00 18 00
[  699.075198] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 88 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
[  699.076443] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  699.076444] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  699.076446] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  699.076448] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 38 00
[  699.076450] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 120 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 7 prio class 0
[  699.078317] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  699.078320] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  699.078322] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  699.078323] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 b8 00 00 90 00
[  699.078325] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 184 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 18 prio class 0
[  699.079568] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  699.079571] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  699.079574] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  699.079576] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 58 00 00 08 00
[  699.079579] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 88 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  699.079582] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 4, async page read
[  699.080831] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  699.080832] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  699.080834] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[  699.080835] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 b8 00 00 08 00
[  699.080837] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 184 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  699.080839] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 16, async page read
[  864.278331] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 4505.817188] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 4505.927791] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[ 4505.927795] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4505.927797] usb 2-1.2: Product: Silicon-Power
[ 4505.927798] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: UFD 2.0
[ 4505.927800] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 1402036101500139
[ 4505.928229] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4505.928574] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 4507.418940] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UFD 2.0  Silicon-Power8G  1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 4507.419397] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4507.420173] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 15730688 512-byte logical blocks: (8.05 GB/7.50 GiB)
[ 4507.420999] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 4507.421002] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 4507.421896] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 4507.421904] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4507.428405]  sdc: sdc1
[ 4507.431647] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5421.829958] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5421.829961] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 5421.829963] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 5421.829966] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 78 04 18 00 00 08 00
[ 5421.829969] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 7865368 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 5421.831829] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 5421.831832] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 5421.831834] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 5421.831837] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 78 04 18 00 00 08 00
[ 5421.831839] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 7865368 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 5421.831843] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865312, async page read
[ 5421.831845] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865313, async page read
[ 5421.831847] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865314, async page read
[ 5421.831849] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865315, async page read
[ 5421.831850] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865316, async page read
[ 5421.831852] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865317, async page read
[ 5421.831853] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865318, async page read
[ 5421.831855] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 7865319, async page read
[ 5429.178684] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 5431.780821] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 5431.891402] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[ 5431.891405] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5431.891407] usb 2-1.2: Product: Silicon-Power
[ 5431.891408] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: UFD 2.0
[ 5431.891410] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 1402036101500139
[ 5431.891867] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 5431.892187] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 5433.361870] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UFD 2.0  Silicon-Power8G  1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 5433.362263] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 5433.363053] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 15730688 512-byte logical blocks: (8.05 GB/7.50 GiB)
[ 5433.363954] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 5433.363958] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 5433.364903] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 5433.364921] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 5433.369906]  sdc: sdc1
[ 5433.373265] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`mtab`:

```
/dev/sdc1 /media/hostel/2571E5907D95FE34 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Comment: «диск был успешно извлечен» — это точная цитата попапа?

Comment: @andreymal, да точная. приложил шот к вопросу.

Comment: У меня подвисает и попуп появляется после sync. Можент обновитесь?

Comment: @eri, согласен что в новом ПО меньше багов (или скорее новые :) ). Но 16.04 таки не новичок. Неужели там нет банального `sync`, тогда что вообще этот пункт делает? Удаляет пиктограмму из бокового меню? Я даже не проблему хочу решить, а скорее понять, почему это так. Допустим, нажали "извлечь", логично, что нужно `sync`. А может быть, ОС просто (ХЗ что делает). А может быть проблема в китайской флешке, которая сначала пишет с "космической" скоростью, а потом резко снижает обороты. Может быть баг не только в ОС, а в "недосказанности" ОС <=> китайская флешка, а `sync` решает эту проблемую

Comment: @eri под "недосказанностью" я имею в виду, что и ОС, и флешка следуют спеке, но есть нюансы, и поэтому нет "виновных", а `sync` тупо в итоге вызывает какую-то аппаратную функцию (через ОС), которая реально проверяет, скинуты ли буфферы и можно ли вырубать питание. `У меня подвисает и попуп появляется после sync` - какая у вас версия и дистро?

Comment: Все флешки буферизуются в линукс, это дело именно ядра. Какая файловая система на флешке? Может стоит поискать ответ в ченьджлогах

Comment: @TotalPusher синк не делает ничего. Он просто барьер, который завершается когда всё io что было в момент sync завершится

Comment: Вот почему unmount у вас не синхронизуется - не понятно. Давайте посмотрим mtab и dmesg.

Comment: @eri, ядро `5.3.7-050307-generic`. Файловая система NTFS (честно не помню почему такую выбрал, флешку потом в android телек вставляю). `У меня подвисает и попуп появляется после sync` - какая у вас версия и дистро? `поискать ответ в ченьджлогах` - хм... это каких? Ядра, Ubuntu или чего-то еще?

Comment: Ntfs в убунте может быть на драйвере fuse и тогда ядро не знает что нельзя извлекать флешку. Давай посмотрим mtab

Comment: @eri  добавил в вопрос mtab и dmesg, dmesg - я не сильно с ним работал, поэтому не знаю попало в лог или нет, брал с конца и до момента который посчитал нужным. И как назло, "извлечь" сработало без проблем, проверял по md5sum. Но проблема точно есть, повторяется. Попробую в следующий раз не использовать `sync`, словить проблему и написать подробнее dmesg. Спасибо!

Comment: @TotalPusher fuse, как и подумал) попробуй ntfs-3g поставить

Comment: @eri, вы просто кладезь полезной информации :) . обязательно попробую!

Comment: @TotalPusher или удалить наоборот - я уж забыл какой нтфс какие глюки дает. Не пользуюсь им 3 года после того как 1с на sql перевели на работе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файловая система NTFS реализованна в базовых вещах, возможно не доделанна синхронизация с дисковым вводом-выводом в Вашей версии. Например до сих пор нет утилит проверки фс. Чтоб вылечить флешку с нтфс иногда требуется **2 раза** вставить её в винду и выполнить проверку после долгого использования в линуксе. Рекомендую попробовать exFAT или vFAT - они лучше подходят для переносимых устройств.

Как я и предположил - драйвер fuse. Этот драйвер выполняется как отдельная программа, а не в ядре и ядро понятия не имеет о его синхронизации с диском. Можно попробовать поставить драйвер `ntfs-3g` или наоборот - я уж забыл как там правильней.